# How to integrate javascript code in my html?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm very new to writing code in html and javascript and am wondering why my script tags aren't producing any output when I open my html file. I've tried console.log, document.write, alert, etc, and none of them seem to be appearing in my code. Nevermind the content of the code, its not at all important.

picture of my code

[image]

Comment: Your HTML is very invalid, your code should not be an image, and you should not use smart quotes.

Comment: You should utilize the code blocks and post some relevant code inline along with your question.

Comment: put all your js code in <script></script> tag for inline js. Or link to external js. And haven't you heard about google

Comment: Your code has curly quotes (`“”`) in several locations that should be using straight quotes (`"`). Disable the "smart quotes" substitution in TextEdit.

Comment: There are quite a number of errors, your URL protocol should be `http://` instead of `http:://` (note the double colons, which is wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Dont use ***write*** but ***alert***

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Everything Potatoes</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Heelo Moto</h1>
  <script>
   alert("Hello mojo");
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```